# Dialogflow API HTTP Request to query Agent not working

Tags: node.js, api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

Recently I've been having some problems using the **Dialogflow API** from a **nodeJs server**...
So I have a **chatbot GUI that sends HTTP requests to the dialogflow agent (using dialogflow API v1)**, and this one, based on the user query should send a response.
But NOW, IT sends an error **401 unauthorized**, knowing that none of the code has been updated since!
I've put the function that calls dialogflow API and added some console.log() to debug. the bug is inside the function textRequest.

```
import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript'


const client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: MY_ACCESS_TOKEN});

methods: {
        dialogflowRequest(queryText){
            document.querySelector('.submit-input').style.opacity = '0.5';
            console.log("==> dialogflow request");
            client.textRequest(queryText).then((response) => {
                console.log("==> client request");
                if(response.result.action == "input.unknown" && this.config.app.googleIt == true){
                    response.result.fulfillment.messages[0].unknown = true
                    response.result.fulfillment.messages[0].text = response.result.resolvedQuery
                } 

                document.querySelector('.submit-input').style.opacity = '1';

                //this.speak(response);
                this.handle(response);
                // VueJS will update the HTML automatically
                this.answers.push(response);

                //reset query and speech
                this.query = '';
                this.speech = config.locale.strings.voiceTitle;
            }).catch((error) => {console.log("unable to log into dialogflow!!!");console.log(error);})
        }
```

POST https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910 401 (Unauthorized)

==> AFTER SOME INSPECTION

**{"status":{"code":401,"errorType":"unauthorized","errorDetails":"Authentication parameters missing"}}**